# how to add multiple columns in combobox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i made a programe to populate more than one columns in combobox.my programe is wrong.could you please say how to do this..please give the code for that..my code is given below,

Dim conobj As Class1

```
    conobj = New Class1
    conobj.connection()

   Dim str2 = "select vc_schno,dt_from,dt_to from ***** etc"
    conobj.readdata(str2)
    Cb_schedule.DataSource = conobj.ds.Tables(0)
    Cb_schedule.DisplayMember = "vc_schno,dt_from,dt_to"
    Cb_schedule.ValueMember = "vc_schno"
```

Answer (score 0):

@achu

If this is what you mean:

If you just want to show more than one column in combobox you can always concat two fields in query itself

Ex:

conobj = New Class1
    conobj.connection()

Dim str2 = "select concat(vc_schno,'-'dt_from'-'dt_to)as field1,vc_schno from ***** etc"
    conobj.readdata(str2)
    Cb_schedule.DataSource = conobj.ds.Tables(0)
    Cb_schedule.DisplayMember = "field1 "
    Cb_schedule.ValueMember = "vc_schno"

Comment: withouth concat how to populate these

Comment: you can use draw item event of combobox to add mutliple column https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982498 try this example